# speechSynthesis in Android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm looking at an Android app trying to get TTS capabilities for reading content. Right now, I'm limited to a webview for displaying content, and have a button to turn TTS on. Unfortunately, `window.speechSynthesis` is undefined, so I can't get voices to use.

Is speechSynthesis just not supported by Android webviews?

Comment: The [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=487255) appears open and active.